# Font in Next.js / Tailwind CSS app initially bold but then unintentionally reverts

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a pretty bare bones Next app using Tailwind and I just installed a custom variable-weight font [Raleway](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway#standard-styles) (downloaded the family in `.ttf` format and converted it to `.woff2`) but for some reason am unable to change the font weight via the `font-bold`, `font-extrabold`, etc custom classes... at least permanently. The Raleway font *is* successfully showing at all to begin with.

Shown below, a refresh makes the page immediately flash with what's seemingly the correct style but then reverts to something else.

[image: The ephemeral, initially-present bold text upon refreshing.]

Could it have something to do with the font block period transitioning to the font swap period? Below is my `styles/globals.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Raleway';
        src: url('/fonts/Raleway-Thin.woff2') format('woff2');
        font-weight: 400;
        font-display: swap;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

And here's my `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        raleway: ['Raleway', 'sans-serif'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 4):

it's because the `.ttf` file you converted only contains the thin weight (font-weight: 100)  of the Raleway font. You need all the weight for this to work.

Example for Poppins :

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Thin.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf')
        format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
...
```

The flash you see is the default browser font because of the display `swap`